# Object Mode Vertex Snapping is not working as intended

Tags: snapping, object-mode

[image]

Instead of snapping the two triangles together it offsets it like this, how do I fix this? I am hovering to the closest vertex which is the bottom one and it keeps off setting the position rather than putting the two points together.

Blender 2.8

Comment: Hello and Welcome. Would you like sharing a screenshot of your snapping settings? Thanks.